# How to create a server side login for PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, jquery-mobile

looking for some assistance here. I'm doing a small project and I'm really struggling to create a login system for my mobile application. I'm using jQuery Mobile as well as MySQL for my database.

What I'm looking to do:

- Create a log in with the database's credentials (please see photo)
- Depending on what type they are, teacher or school, direct them to their respective teacher.html / school.html files.

I have my config.php and connect.php files ready to go but I'm unsure of what to be writing to check the credentials.

Please find a snippet below.

```css
/* Global Font */

* {
  font-family: helvetica neue;
}


/* Login landing screen */

#LandingButtons {
  font-family: helvetica neue;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 87%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 1.4vw;
  width: 100vw;
}

#registrationButton {
  background-color: #4B836E;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

#loginButton {
  background-color: #5D93CD;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

.landingsliderimg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

button.ui-btn.ui-btn-inline {
  width: 45%;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #d3c208;
}

.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-btn-a.ui-btn-inline.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
  width: 37.5%;
}

#popupMenu {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}


/* REGISTRATION PAGE */


/* HEADER */

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 44px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px #00000042;
}

.header .h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 44px;
}

.header.ui-header.ui-bar-inherit.ui-header-fixed.slidedown {
  background-color: #229aab;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-size: 3vh;
}

.ui-btn-left.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-icon-user.ui-btn-icon-left.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #219aab;
  border-color: #d8d8d8;
}

#registrationForm {
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 10vw;
  margin-top: 3vh;
}


/* Hide / Show Forms */

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Mobile Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--jQuery CDN Hosted Files-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

  <!--User's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Login and register buttons -->
  <div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div id="LandingButtons">
      <a href="#registration" id="registrationButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-transition="slide">REGISTER</a>
      <a href="#popupLogin" id="loginButton" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-transition="pop">LOGIN</a>

      <div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-position-to="window">
          <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
              <h3>Please sign in</h3>
              <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="email">
              <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password">
              <button type="submit" data-icon="check">Sign in</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>



  <!-- Header -->
  <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>Registration
  </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: The few credentials I have in my database]

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that someone is still using jQuery Mobile but I think I have most of the code you need.

Several years ago I wrote an article covering a complex jQuery Mobile authorization tutorial: https://www.gajotres.net/complex-jquery-mobile-authorization-example/

The main idea is to post your authorization information from jQM client:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
          $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
        });
    </script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">       
            <h3>Login Page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <form id="check-user" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
                    </div>                                 
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                     
                        <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
                        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
            </form>                             
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a href="#login" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-delete" id="back-btn">Back</a>      
            <h3>Welcome Page</h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>Page footer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Forward this information to server side PHP. Of course you will need to handle DB read/write; my example use some kind of ORM, for example Propel as it has a large number of available tutorials.

```
<?php
function authorize()
{
  //normally this info would be pulled from a database.
  //build JSON array
  $status = array("status" => "success"); 

  return $status;
}

$possible_params = array("authorization", "test");

$value = "An error has occurred";

if (isset($_POST["action"]) && in_array($_POST["action"], $possible_params))
{
  switch ($_POST["action"])
    {
      case "authorization":
        $value = authorize();
        break;
    }
}

//return JSON array
exit(json_encode($value));
?>
```

Get response back to jQuery Mobile and depending on a page type, open appropriate page using:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#second");
```

Here's a whole jQM example from my tutorial:

```
var userHandler = {
    username : '',
    status : ''
}

$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage');
    if(activePage.attr('id') === 'login') {
        $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
            if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){

                userHandler.username = $('#username').val();

                // Send data to server through the Ajax call
                // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
                $.ajax({url: 'auth.php',
                    data: {action : 'authorization', formData : $('#check-user').serialize()},
                    type: 'post',                  
                    async: 'true',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                        $.mobile.loading('show'); // This will show Ajax spinner
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete   
                        $.mobile.loading('hide'); // This will hide Ajax spinner
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        // Check if authorization process was successful
                        if(result.status == 'success') {
                            userHandler.status = result.status;
                            $.mobile.changePage("#second");                        
                        } else {
                            alert('Logon unsuccessful!');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request,error) {
                        // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                        alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                    }
                });                  
            } else {
                alert('Please fill all necessary fields');
            }          
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });  
    } else if(activePage.attr('id') === 'second') {
        activePage.find('.ui-content').text('Wellcome ' + userHandler.username);
    }
});

$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforechange', function (e, ui) {
    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage');
    if(activePage.attr('id') === 'second') {
        var to = ui.toPage;

        if (typeof to  === 'string') {
            var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
            to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);

            if (to === '#login' && userHandler.status === 'success') {
                alert('You cant open a login page while youre still logged on!');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                // remove active status on a button if a transition was triggered with a button
                $('#back-btn').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-shadow').css({'box-shadow':'0 0 0 #3388CC'});
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

Above tutorial is written in jQuery Mobile 1.4.5. While there's already a version 1.5 it is still an alpha version and there's a good chance we will never see a RC version of 1.5, so stick to 1.4.5.

Again you only need to write PHP DB handling implementation and that should not take you that much time if you stick to Propel ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your php file looks like as you have not provided the code...

But here is a mockup example of the front-end js and html.

Place js in between head tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#insert").click(function () {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
                alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
                return false;
            }

            var password = $("#password").val();
            if(password.length < 5){
                alert("Please ensure password is longer than 5 characters");
                return false;
            }

            var dataString =
                "email=" + email
                + "&password=" + password
                + "&insert=";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "#yoururl...",
                data: dataString,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#insert").val('Connecting...');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if(data=="teacher")
                    {
                       window.location='teacher.html'
                    }
                    else if(data=="student")
                    {
                        window.location='student.html'
                    }
                 else {
                        alert("Failed to login");

                       }

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

html:

```
 <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" 
        placeholder="Email">
 <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" 
        placeholder="Password">
<button type="submit" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary btn- 
        block" >Login</button>
```

Hope that helps.